# JQuery datatables crashes JS in IE because of console.log

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datatables

I just wanted to share a bug I solved in the datatables component.

Apparently, when something goes wrong in the datatables script it calls _fnLog and outputs the error into the console.

this is the code for the function:

```
function _fnLog(oSettings, iLevel, sMesg) {
        var sAlert = (oSettings === null) ?
            "DataTables warning: " + sMesg :
            "DataTables warning (table id = '" + oSettings.sTableId + "'): " + sMesg;

        if (iLevel === 0) {
            if (DataTable.ext.sErrMode == 'alert') {
                alert(sAlert);
            }
            else {
                throw sAlert;
            }
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (console !== undefined && console.log) {
                console.log(sAlert);
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice the last few lines here are checking if "console" exists and then performing the console.log action. In IE the console object does not exist unless we are running the debugger. This made finding this bug really hard and annoying. Anyway, you can't reference "console" just like that. IE stops the script with no exception. You must qualify it with "window" so the proper script is

```
if (window.console !== undefined && console.log) {
      window.console.log(sAlert);
}
```

I hope this was helpful because I just spent an hour on this :)

Eyal

Comment: Nice finding, forward it to alan the datatables creator.

Comment: Paul Irish has a nice way of solving this: http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/